# Rspec cannot load error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

Running this (bundle exec rspec spec/requests/static_pages_spec.rb) worked fine yesterday, but today when I go back into my environment (Aptana) I get the following errors:

```
/Users/sa/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/rspec-core-2.10.1/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:746:in `load': c
annot load such file -- /Users/sa/Documents/AptanaWorkspace/receiver/spec/spec/requests/static_pages_spec
.rb (LoadError)
        from /Users/sa/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/rspec-core-2.10.1/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:746
:in `block in load_spec_files'
        from /Users/sa/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/rspec-core-2.10.1/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:746
:in `map'
        from /Users/sa/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/rspec-core-2.10.1/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:746
:in `load_spec_files'
        from /Users/sa/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/rspec-core-2.10.1/lib/rspec/core/command_line.rb:22:i
n `run'
        from /Users/sa/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/rspec-core-2.10.1/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:69:in `run
'
        from /Users/sa/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/rspec-core-2.10.1/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:10:in `blo
ck in autorun'
```

I'm stumped as I've checked all references and am trying to run this from my app's root directory.  All assistance is greatly appreciated.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
cannot load such file -- /Users/sa/Documents/AptanaWorkspace/receiver/spec/spec/requests/static_pages_spec.rb (LoadError)
```

Looks like you've got an extra `/spec` in there, probably should be  `/Users/sa/Documents/AptanaWorkspace/receiver/spec/requests/static_pages_spec.rb`. Are you sure you haven't changed anything?

Comment: thanks.  I'll look back through my commits to ensure nothing changed.