# Rspec having issues with file path

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

I am basically having the exact same issue as this user on this question:
[Rspec cannot load error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12101697/rspec-cannot-load-error)

Specifically, when I look at the error log, I see that for some reason it is adding an extra "/spec" to the file path in loading the static_pages_spec.rb file

```
/Users/anantvinjamoori/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1@railstutorial_rails_4_0/gems/rspec-core-
2.13.1/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:819:in `load': cannot load such file --      

/Users/anantvinjamoori/helpondemand/sample_app2/spec/spec/requests/static_pages_spec.rb   
(LoadError)
```

This directory does not exist on my computer, so it is no surprise that this error is being generated. However, I am not sure how to stop it from doing this. The previous user just said he "would check his commits" and never followed up. How can I stop RSpec from doing this incorrect path assignment?

Answer (score 0):

Because it seems others have had this problem, thought I would contribute my mistake (even though it may seem stupid)

I was executing rspec from the wrong directory from the terminal (ie i was executing it from the spec directory itself, which was probably the reason the extra /spec was being added.

Bottom line: restarting your terminal never hurts!